# Swift 3 increment increment tab bar badge

Tags: ios, swift

I am trying to increment the tab bar badge once I get a notification.

In swift2.1 this worked:

```
if let badgeValue = tabBarController?.tabBar.items?[1].badgeValue,
    nextValue = Int(badgeValue)?.successor() {
    tabBarController?.tabBar.items?[1].badgeValue = String(nextValue)
} else {
    tabBarController?.tabBar.items?[1].badgeValue = "1"
}
```

But is there any other way to make this work in Swift 3? The `successor()` does not work